# Start spring-boot app without depending on username and password for Database oracle?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jwt

Is it possible to start a spring boot application without knowing the username and password of the data source in first , it will recover after authentication on the front end. I use Jwt for authentication , And i want all of my application users are also DB oracle users.

Comment: How can your application connect to a database if it doesn't have credentials to the database?

Comment: For the first time I want the application start without connecting to any database, but once a user tries to authenticate we will use his username and password to create the connection with the database. The goal is that we want to benefit from the authentication of the oracle database and that they are the sameapplication users  are also DB the oracle users.

Comment: Unless this is some kind of desktop application where that information can be provided at application start-up, I don't really think this is possible.  A webapp with a data store *must* be connected to the data store at startup to do anything.

Comment: I tried to do this with spring security and jdbc template without using JPA and it worked fine, and I don't know how to do it with jwt and spring jpa. I'm just want to  remove username and password from application.proprties configuration file for security reasons and also because the data source users changes according to each user of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able do it with spring jpa. However you can do it in traditional Hibernate or JPA way, where you can create a Singleton class (lazy loading) with SessionFactory  initialized. But that way you lose all the autowiring and other spring jpa features. Also its not recommended.

Comment: Please could you explain to me more , and if you have any sources that can help me i will be grateful,Thank you.